# Обращение к глобальным переменным из другого документа

Tags: javascript, global-variables

Есть два HTML-документа `first.html` и `second.html`, и два JS-файла `first.js` и `second.js`.

Я объявляю две глобальные переменные:

```
let arr=[]; 
let str = "Hello Kitty!";
```

В документе `first.html` по нажатию на кнопку срабатывает функция, которая присваивает новые значения для `arr` и `str`.

После нажатия на кнопку, я запускаю второй документ `second.html` для которого в скрипте `second.js` пытаюсь обратиться к переменным из первого скрипта `first.js`.

Но документ выводит значения первоначальные, а мне нужны уже измененные.

Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать?

first.html:

```
<head>
  <script src="first.js"></script>  
</head>
<body>       
  <button id="btn">KNOPKA</button>
</body>
```

first.js:

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init);
let arr = [];
let str = "Hello Kitty!";

function buttonClick() {
    arr = [1, 2, 3];
    str = "Hello Dolly";
}

function init() {
    let button = document.getElementById("btn");
    button.addEventListener("click", function() {
        buttonClick()
    });
}
```

second.html:

```
<body>
  <script src="first.js"></script> 
  <script src="second.js"></script>         
</body>
```

second.js:

```
alert(arr);
alert(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

В Вашем случае Вы переходите на новую страницу, где загружаете оба файла со скриптами по новой, соответственно значения будут приведены к исходным.

Обьявите требуемые Вам переменные **один раз** на той странице, которая будет загружена первой, например на `index.html`, после чего Вы сможете обращаться к ним из обоих ваших файлов:

```
// head tag файла index.html  
<script>
  let arr = []
  let str = "Hello Kitty!"
</script>
```

Comment: Изменил! Значения стали оба undefined

Answer (score 1):

Лучше будет присвоить их глобальному объекту window перед загрузкой скриптов:

```html
// head tag файла index.html  
<script>
  window.arr = []
  window.str = "Hello Kitty!"
</script>
```

Comment: Изменил! И там и там. ничего не изменилось. выводятся первоначальные значения.

Answer (score 0):

Решил ВОПРОС так. Использовал localStorage. Правда он хранит строковые значения, но ничего Джаваскрипт всемогущ, можно переделать!!!!!!